# How to imitate click on file input?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click, file-io

HTML:

```
<div class="fileinputs">
    <input type="file" name="postgallery_set-0-image_0" id="id_postgallery_set-0-image_0">
    <div class="fakefile">
        <img src="/img/image_choice.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.fileinputs {
            position: relative;
        }

        div.fakefile {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 1;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .fileinputs input {
            position: relative;
            text-align: right;
            -moz-opacity:0 ;
            filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 2;
        }
```

And JS:

```
$('.fakefile').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('input').click();
});
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox.
In IE8, the following occurs:
everything works fine, but when submitting the form file input is cleared, the form is not sent and the cursor is placed on a hidden file input, how to make it work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need JS to achieve this effect. HTML `<label>`s are for just this kind of thing. e.g.

```
<div class="fileinputs">
  <input type="file" name="postgallery_set-0-image_0" id="id_postgallery_set-0-image_0">
  <label for="id_postgallery_set-0-image_0">
    <img src="/img/image_choice.png" />
  </label>
</div>
```